# ERROR: Could not build wheels for imagecodecs, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, installation, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory, tiff

I write "!pip install apeer-ometiff-library" to install it in google Colab but it gives an error as below:

```
Collecting apeer-ometiff-library
  Downloading apeer_ometiff_library-1.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from apeer-ometiff-library) (1.22.4)
Collecting tifffile==2020.6.3 (from apeer-ometiff-library)
  Downloading tifffile-2020.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 133.2/133.2 kB 3.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting imagecodecs==2020.5.30 (from apeer-ometiff-library)
  Downloading imagecodecs-2020.5.30.tar.gz (9.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9.0/9.0 MB 4.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: imagecodecs
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for imagecodecs (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for imagecodecs
  Running setup.py clean for imagecodecs
Failed to build imagecodecs
ERROR: Could not build wheels for imagecodecs, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I would appreciate it if you let me know how I can fix it
Thanks

I think the problem is with imagecodecs but I could not find a solution by trying online guides

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is problem going on with the `wheels for imagecodecs`

I also got the same error while trying to install in my google Colab.

[image]

---

Here is a github issue link:
https://github.com/MouseLand/cellpose/issues/742